# how do I show multiple fields of the entity referenced

Tags: drupal-7, entity

I have a first content type that's referencing another content type with fields called title, phone, email and room. I'd like to reference all those fields into my first content type, but when I set up an entity reference as a field in the first content type, I only get the title, and not even as a link. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

For link on title please check 'Manage Display' option under edit content type.

Thanks
Cheers!!!